# Formula to auto sum range adjusting for each column for a fixed number of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a project that is of variable length, denoted in D2 as 39 Months. In cell H1 I have the following - =EDATE($B$2, SEQUENCE(1, $D$2, 0)) which automatically calculaes the months for the duration of the project. I'd like to create a function that will automatically add the values in H3 and H4 then I3 and I4 etc. So in H5 I have =SUM(H3:H4), is there anyway I can paste a function into H5 that will sum each of the columns for the duration of the project?

[image: Auto Sum Range]

Comment: It would be clearer if you add a screenshot of what you have and what you expect.

Comment: "I'd like to create a function that will automatically add the values in H3 and H4 then I3 and I4 etc." What values?

Comment: H5 could hold this: `=BYCOL(INDEX($1:$1048576,{3;4},SEQUENCE(1,D2,COLUMN(H:H))),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))`

Comment: Not sure why the image didn’t attach. I’ll re-attach when home and hopefully it’ll make things clear. 

H5 has Sum(H3:H4), I5 has Sum(I3:I4), J5 has Sum(J3:J4) etc. I’d like to find a solution that’ll allow me to paste a function into H5 that will calculate the Sums for the subsequent cells up to a fixed number of cells in another cell, in my case 39 in D2.

Comment: Have you tried my formula? It indexes al rows 3 and 4 from column H and the next `n` columns, where `n` is the value in `D2`. Then sumns the indexed range column by column.

Comment: I’m actually out at the moment, I’ll give it a shot when I get back and let you know how I get on thanks.

Comment: I posted it as answer, so others don't think it's unsolved

Comment: Is there a way to auto multiply each cell for the duration of the project in the same way, starting at I6 by the fixed Rate E2 to get a monthly revenue, so I have a new row with =SUM(H2*$E$2), then =SUM(I2*$E$2) etc to calculate the revenue for each month, it'd be great if this could auto calculate with a forumla in I6 too. Is there also a way to adjust the function to instead of adding two adjacent row cells, to instead subtract them for the same period of time denoted by D2 to find the P&L for the month, so =SUM(H6-H5) where the row 5 will be the monthly revenue and row 6 the Monthly P&L?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=BYCOL(INDEX($1:$1048576,{3;4},SEQUENCE(1,D2,8)),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))`

It indexes al rows 3 and 4 from column H and the next n columns, where n is the value in D2. Then sums the indexed range column-by-column.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, in H5 you want to get the column sums of the 2 fixed arrays in H3 and H4 for the length given by D2

You could use this formula in H5

```
=MMULT({1,1},OFFSET(H3:H4,0,0,,D2))
```

which is the same as

```
=OFFSET(H3,0,0,,D2)+OFFSET(H4,0,0,,D2)
```

Although the first solution can more easily be extended for additional rows.
In case of significantly more rows, `{1,1}` can be replaced by `SEQUENCE(1,x,1,0)` where x is the number of rows. For the given example, the formula would then be

```
=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(H3:H4),1,0),OFFSET(H3:H4,0,0,,D2))
```